# Second function with getJSON not executing

Tags: javascript, jquery

As the title says, I am trying to make a weather app which takes the users location and gets their local weather. I am stuck on the second function which will not execute and the console.log(); isn't providing any output. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function getLocation() {
        $.getJSON("http://ipinfo.io", function (response) {
            var cc = response.country;
            var city = response.city;
            var state = response.region;
            $(".city").html(city + "," + state);
            console.log(cc);
            var url = "api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city + "," + cc + "&APPID=1d0e324c03cd19ecf0abf20ac2708666";
            console.log(city);
            console.log(url);
            getWeather(url);

        });
    }
    function getWeather(url) {
        $.getJSON(url, function (response) {

            console.log(url);
            $(".temp").html(Math.round(response.main.temp));

        });
    }
    getLocation();

});
```

Comment: Is `url` for `getWeather` correct?

Comment: did you check console for errors?

Comment: any error you got?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

change the url in this way:

```
var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+city+","+cc+"&APPID=1d0e324c03cd19ecf0abf20ac2708666";
```

you were missing http

Answer (score 2):

URL for Weather API is incorrect, You need to use `http://` with API otherwise its treated as relative URL.

*Use*

```
var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + ...
```

```js
function getLocation() {
  $.getJSON("http://ipinfo.io", function(response) {
   // console.log(response);
    var cc = response.country;
    var city = response.city;
    var state = response.region;
    //Updated the API
    var url = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + city + "," + cc + "&APPID=1d0e324c03cd19ecf0abf20ac2708666";
    getWeather(url);
  });
}

function getWeather(url) {
  $.getJSON(url, function(response) {
    console.log(response);
  });
}
getLocation();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```